# Prove the process is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, martingales

Let $\{M_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a symmetric simple random walk. Fix a real $b$. Prove that the process $S_n = e^{bM_n} (\frac{2}{e^b + e^{-b}})^n$, $n = 0,1,2,....$, is a martingale w.r.t. the natural filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\ge 0}$.

I know that a stochastic process is called a martingale if $E[M_{t+s} | \mathcal{F}] = M_t$ but I am confused about how to start this proof. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Often the start point of a martingale proof related to Brownian motion/random walk/general Markov processes is to start by splitting $X_t$ into $(X_t-X_s)+X_s$ and looking at the increments.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that $M_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable hence so is $S_n$, and $M_n$ is integrable since it is bounded.

It remains to check that $\mathbb E(S_{n+1} \mid \mathcal F_n)=S_n$. To this aim, we have to compute $\mathbb E(e^{bM_{n+1}} \mid \mathcal F_n)$. As $$e^{bM_{n+1}}=\underbrace{e^{bM_{n+1}-bM_n}}_{\mbox{independent of }\mathcal F_n}\cdot \underbrace{e^{bM_{n}}}_{\mathcal F_n\mbox{-measurable}},$$
we get 
$$\mathbb E(e^{bM_{n+1}} \mid \mathcal F_n)=e^{bM_{n}}\mathbb E(e^{bM_{n+1}-bM_n}).$$

Comment: How do we know what $\mathbb E(e^{bM_{n+1}-bM_n})$ is?

Comment: Since $(M_n)$ is a symmetric simple random walk, $M_{n+1}-M_n$ takes the values $1$ and $-1$ with respective probabilities $1/2$.